# Symfony bin/console breaking with env arg

Tags: symfony, yaml, symfony-console

Using Symfony 6.2, running:

`bin/console list`

Works as expected - shows me a list of commands. However, running the same command using the prod env flag, gives me an error:

`bin/console -e prod list`

```
Expected to find class "[My local classname]" in file "[path to my local classname]"
while importing services from resource "../src/", but it was not found! 
Check the namespace prefix used with the resource in [docroot]/config/services.yaml
 (which is being imported from "[docroot]/src/Kernel.php").
```

The `my classname` file exists and works as expected (ie, I'm using it fine in the  `dev` env), and the `Kernel.php` file is boilerplate.

How do I avoid this? Isn't the prod env using the same `services.yaml` file?

Comment: Two things you can test. First is using your command like bin/console -eprod list, it's how I do it. Second is to check if you don't have a specific configuration for PROD because yes you can create various config for each kind of env

Comment: Try clearing your prod cache first - `bin/console cache:clear -e prod`

Comment: Thx @skuti Fracsi - getting the same error when I try either of your commands : /

Answer (score 1):

Doh - the file for the `my class` class the error referenced did not have a namespace declared...

[insert facepalm]